# ExpressJS - How to use JWT received by Auth RestAPI

Tags: jquery, node.js, jwt, backend, rest

I have built a User REST-API (using ExpressJS) that performs CRUD operation on User (account) data and Tasks that belong to a particular user. The API returns a JWT if a user is successfully authenticated.

I am now  building is a simple front-end web application (i only know Jquery) to test these CRUD functions out. I am using $.ajax to send a post request (contain username & password) and receive JWT.

The problem is I am now totally confused about what to do next for the client app.

My questions are:

- Where to store the JWT (Cookies, sessionStorage, LocalStorage)?
- After storing the JWT, how can I set up the client app:
  +  A single-page app only uses AJAX to request dynamic data?
  +  A dynamic web application using MVC and template engine (utilize HTML  to request page with dynamic data )?
  +  Maybe a hybrid of the two above?

I really want to know how front-end and back-end APIs are commonly talking with each other nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

Glad to know someone is stuck on this, I had the same doubt a couple of years back.

**Getting straight to the answer**
So as your API is able to return a JWT token there are few things to be considered. As you are using Jquery so I am assuming that your frontend tech is not protecting you out of the box from simple XSS attacks, so it would not be a good idea to store your token in Local storage and any other storage that is accessible by JS in frontend. so Our go-to will be HTTP-only cookies.

If you were using something like React then you could have used Localstorage too.

Now, how are we going to get your JWT with every request to validate a request at the backend?
the answer is very simple if you are using HTTP only cookies or for that matter any cookie you will have access to the cookies with every request.

**side note:** You need to enable certain flags for that.

In the other case, you can send JWT with your request in the body(make sure you are using HTTPS :D ).

Then at the backend, you can create a middleware to validate the requests using the JWT that you just received.

Let me know if there is anything else I can clarify for you.

Comment: These are very useful, thank you ! . I have seen other using JWT in request's Authentication header. What are the use cases for that ?

Comment: Actually my bad, we should send JWT as a Auth Header not body, reason! We don't have body for a GET request.